# List of lists: indexing and assigning values (Python)

Tags: python

I'm sure this is stupid simple, but somehow I can't figure it out.

```
a=[[0]*4]*3
a[0][0]=1

a
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I'm trying to assign 1 to only the first element in the first row. Instead, the first element in *every* row got assigned a value of 1. How should I do the indexing so that value is assigned to the proper element?

Thanks!

Comment: For multidimensional arrays, you may also want to take a look at [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html).  In this case, `a = numpy.zeros((3, 4))` would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should realize this fact.

If you do

```
a = [5] * 3
```

surprisingly these `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]` are same object.
You can ensure it by doing this.

```
id(a[0]) ==  id(a[1]) ==  id(a[2])
#True
```

So it indicate like following.

```
a[0] --+
a[1] --+--> 5
a[2] --+
```

If you do

```
a[0] = 10
```

then it becomes like following.

```
a[0] -----> 10
a[1] --+--> 5
a[2] --+
```

OK. Now back to your list of list problem.
To make your problem simple define `a` as:

```
a = [[4, 5, 6]] * 3
```

Unsurprisingly these are same object.

```
id(a[0]) ==  id(a[1]) ==  id(a[2])
#True
```

So it indicate like following.

```
a[0] --+
a[1] --+--> [4, 5, 6]
a[2] --+
```

If you do

```
a[0] = 10
```

then it becomes like following.

```
a[0] -----> 10
a[1] --+--> [4, 5, 6]
a[2] --+
```

OK. It's no problem. Then you do

```
a[1][0] = 8
```

then it becomes like following.

```
a[0] -----> 10
a[1] --+--> [8, 5, 6]
a[2] --+
```

Done!! It's easy to understand.

HIH.:)

Answer (score 0):

The indexing is fine; its how you created/filled `a` that is the problem.  You made each "row" a copy of the same list.

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting. Thanks. So how should I preallocate, say, a 3x4 matrix using lists?  Should I resort to something like a=[[0 for x in range(4)] for x in range(3)]? 
**Also,**
I found that for a=[0]*4; a[0]=1, the assignment is made properly.  How come not every element of 'a' gets changed?  Aren't they all copied from the same list [0]?

Comment: It is true that all of the individual elements (numbers) are all the same object.  But you are not modifying any of those; you are REPLACING some of them by modifying a list, a list which has been cloned to make each of your rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't that your indexing is wrong, it's that all three elements of the top-level list are, in fact, just references to the same list object. You need to make sure you make separate lists:

```
>>> a = [[0]*4 for _ in range(3)]
>>> a[0][0] = 1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

It looks like you're trying to make some sort of matrix or multidimensional array. Have you considered using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/)?

Comment: Yeah, I know I should just do something like zeros((3,4)).  I was trying to figure out why the other way didn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are copying references. Each list within the top-level list are essentially the same list. Any modification to one will affect the others. Instead you need to generate a new list for each list you want to add.

```
a = [[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(3)]
a[0][0] = 1
```